# How to do function calling using Azure OpenAI

Tags: azure-openai

Here is my code

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    engine="XXX", # The deployment name you chose when you deployed the ChatGPT or GPT-4 model.
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "Assistant is a large language model trained by OpenAI."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Calculate the circumference of circle with radius 5?"}
    ],
    functions=[{'name': 'circumference_calc', 'description': 'Calculate the circumference of circle given the radius', 'parameters': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'radius': {'description': 'The radius of the circle', 'type': 'number'}}}, 'required': ['radius']}]
)
```

Results in :

**InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions**

Wrote the above code

Comment: I've run into the same problem using langchain agents and openai functions: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/6777

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE (13. July 2023):** Azure now supports function calling in API version `2023-07-01-preview` on these models:

- `gpt-4-0613`
- `gpt-4-32k-0613`
- `gpt-35-turbo-0613` (thanks Joel)
- `gpt-35-turbo-16k-0613`

---

### Previous answer:

Only version `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613` and `gpt-4-0613` has function calling ([ref](https://openai.com/blog/function-calling-and-other-api-updates)), and Azure OpenAI Services only supports these for now ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/models)):

- `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301`
- `gpt-4-0314`
- `gpt-4-32k-0314`

Hopefully, the Azure OpenAI Service team will support the `0613` version soon.

**UPDATE (3. July 2023):** Even though `0613` is out now, it seems like they still don't support `functions` as a parameter, as some others have pointed out here. I have tested using `2023-06-01-preview`, which is supposed to be the newest API interface (according to [these specs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference)) with no luck.. I also found that version `2023-07-01-preview` is working too, now, but no luck there either. (This has now changed. See update on the top^)

Comment: Are you able to find any documentation by Microsoft? Or it is identical to Open AI's implementation

Comment: I have assumed this is the Azure docs, for now: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference/preview/2023-07-01-preview/generated.json#L527 (ChatCompletionsOptions). There are only some minor differences between those "docs" and OpenAIs docs, but from testing I cannot see that any of those differences actually exists (like Azure "docs" says the stop parameter is only an array, but a string works as well). I think you can assume the implementation is identical now. (except for the model parameter for OpenAI)

Comment: In other words, I think you can use OpenAIs docs for reference for now. I have not found any other docs from Microsoft yet

Comment: Managed to put it working with gpt-35-turbo-0613 and gpt-35-turbo-16k. just added the `api_version="2023-07-01-preview",` parameter in the `openai.ChatCompletion.create` function calling.

Comment: @JoelCarneiro do you think this is a glitch/workaround or they supports it but it hasn't published? As I don't want to use it if this won't work in future. Thanks

Comment: Functions with 2023-07-01-preview have been working a few hours during the last weeks already, but it was broken again multiple times. It looks like it's more stable now, but I wouldn't rely on it as long as it's not been announced by Microsoft.

Comment: I can confirm that all listed models are working for me. Thanks for bringing us the good news @NiklasMH

Comment: As per the doc, latest version of the GPT-4 and 35-turbo is not available in all the regions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#gpt-4-models

Answer (score 3):

This has started working now. Make sure that your model version is 0613. I have tested with gpt-35-turbo.

```
import openai

openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_key = "XXX"
openai.api_base = "https://XXXX.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    engine="XXX",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "what is current date?"}],
    functions=[
        {
            "name": "get_current_date",
            "description": "Get the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format",
            "parameters": {"type": "object", "properties": {}, "required": []},
        }
    ],
)
print(response["choices"][0])
```

Response:

```
<OpenAIObject at 0x10d2c1790> JSON: {
  "index": 0,
  "finish_reason": "function_call",
  "message": {
    "role": "assistant",
    "function_call": {
      "name": "get_current_date",
      "arguments": "{}"
    }
  },
  "content_filter_results": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the model version 0613 is available now, the api does not support function calling with the api version "2023-06-01-preview".
Refer to: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference/preview/2023-06-01-preview/inference.json

Answer (score 0):

We will wait with attention for the new version of the nuget https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.AI.OpenAI_1.0.0-beta.5/sdk/openai/Azure.AI.OpenAI/ README.md

Which I suppose that Azure.AI.OpenAI_1.0.0-beta.6 will include the call to functions.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK reference was updated to reflect [Azure Github 2023-07-01-preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference/preview/2023-07-01-preview/generated.json?fbclid=IwAR2XrMVDCFrnTceJppjHLvUxhE1v-2OsXeQH1TID2YJPcfBVW34AwsGW25s) the inclusion of function calling.

From this thread https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/pull/24534  it's clear that for now the Azure OpenAI 0613 version does not follow that updated API yet but should be available very shortly from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an example using the API here: [Recursive Azure OpenAI Function Calling](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/10068)

```
 // *** Define the Functions ***
        string fnTodosPOSTDescription = "Creates a new TODO item. ";
        fnTodosPOSTDescription += "Use this function to add ";
        fnTodosPOSTDescription += "a new TODO item to the list";
        string fnTodosGETDescription = "Retrieves the TODO list. ";
        fnTodosGETDescription += "Use this function to view the TODO list.";
        string fnTodosDELETEDescription = "Deletes a specific TODO item ";
        fnTodosDELETEDescription += "from the list. Use this function to ";
        fnTodosDELETEDescription += "remove a TODO item from the list.";
        var fnTodosPOST = new FunctionDefinition();
        fnTodosPOST.Name = "Todos_POST";
        fnTodosPOST.Description = fnTodosPOSTDescription;
        fnTodosPOST.Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new JsonObject
            {
                ["type"] = "object",
                ["properties"] = new JsonObject
                {
                    ["TodoRequest"] = new JsonObject
                    {
                        ["type"] = "object",
                        ["properties"] = new JsonObject
                        {
                            ["todo"] = new JsonObject
                            {
                                ["type"] = "string",
                                ["description"] = @"The TODO item to be added."
                            }
                        },
                        ["required"] = new JsonArray { "todo" }
                    }
                },
                ["required"] = new JsonArray { "TodoRequest" }
            });
        var fnTodosGET = new FunctionDefinition();
        fnTodosGET.Name = "Todos_GET";
        fnTodosGET.Description = fnTodosGETDescription;
        fnTodosGET.Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new JsonObject
            {
                ["type"] = "object",
                ["properties"] = new JsonObject { }
            });
        var fnTodosDELETE = new FunctionDefinition();
        fnTodosDELETE.Name = "Todos_DELETE";
        fnTodosDELETE.Description = fnTodosDELETEDescription;
        fnTodosDELETE.Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new JsonObject
            {
                ["type"] = "object",
                ["properties"] = new JsonObject
                {
                    ["TodoIndexRequest"] = new JsonObject
                    {
                        ["type"] = "object",
                        ["properties"] = new JsonObject
                        {
                            ["todoIdx"] = new JsonObject
                            {
                                ["type"] = "integer",
                                ["description"] = @"The index of the TODO item to be deleted."
                            }
                        },
                        ["required"] = new JsonArray { "todoIdx" }
                    }
                },
                ["required"] = new JsonArray { "TodoIndexRequest" }
            });
        // Create a new list of FunctionDefinition objects
        List<FunctionDefinition> DefinedFunctions = new List<FunctionDefinition>();
        // Add the FunctionDefinition objects to the list
        DefinedFunctions.Add(fnTodosPOST);
        DefinedFunctions.Add(fnTodosGET);
        DefinedFunctions.Add(fnTodosDELETE);
```

Call Azure OpenAI Service

```
        // Create a new ChatCompletionsOptions object
        var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
            {
                Temperature = (float)0.7,
                MaxTokens = 2000,
                NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
                FrequencyPenalty = 0,
                PresencePenalty = 0,
            };
        chatCompletionsOptions.Functions = DefinedFunctions;
        chatCompletionsOptions.FunctionCall = FunctionDefinition.Auto;
        // Add the prompt to the chatCompletionsOptions object
        foreach (var message in ChatMessages)
        {
            chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(message);
        }
        // Call the GetChatCompletionsAsync method
        Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream =
        await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
            DeploymentOrModelName,
            chatCompletionsOptions);
        // Get the ChatCompletions object from the response
        ChatCompletions result = responseWithoutStream.Value;
        // Create a new Message object with the response and other details
        // and add it to the messages list
        var choice = result.Choices.FirstOrDefault();
        if (choice != null)
        {
            if (choice.Message != null)
            {
                ChatMessages.Add(choice.Message);
            }
        }
        // Update the total number of tokens used by the API
        TotalTokens = TotalTokens + result.Usage.TotalTokens;
```

See if as a response ChatGPT wants to call a function

```
    if (result.Choices.FirstOrDefault().FinishReason == "function_call")
    {
        // Chat GPT wants to call a function
        // To allow ChatGPT to call multiple functions
        // We need to start a While loop
        bool FunctionCallingComplete = false;
        while (!FunctionCallingComplete)
        {
            // Call the function
            ChatMessages = ExecuteFunction(result, ChatMessages);
            // *** Call Azure OpenAI Service ***
            // Get a response from ChatGPT
            // (now that is has the results of the function)
            // Create a new ChatCompletionsOptions object
            chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
                {
                    Temperature = (float)0.7,
                    MaxTokens = 2000,
                    NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
                    FrequencyPenalty = 0,
                    PresencePenalty = 0,
                };
            chatCompletionsOptions.Functions = DefinedFunctions;
            chatCompletionsOptions.FunctionCall = FunctionDefinition.Auto;
            // Add the prompt to the chatCompletionsOptions object
            foreach (var message in ChatMessages)
            {
                chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(message);
            }
            // Call the GetChatCompletionsAsync method
            Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStreamFn =
            await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
                DeploymentOrModelName,
                chatCompletionsOptions);
            // Get the ChatCompletions object from the response
            result = responseWithoutStreamFn.Value;
            var FunctionResult = result.Choices.FirstOrDefault();
            // Create a new Message object with the response and other details
            // and add it to the messages list
            if (FunctionResult.Message != null)
            {
                ChatMessages.Add(FunctionResult.Message);
            }
            if (FunctionResult.FinishReason == "function_call")
            {
                // Keep looping
                FunctionCallingComplete = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Break out of the loop
                FunctionCallingComplete = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Set ErrorMessage to the exception message if an error occurs
    ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    // Clear the prompt variable
    prompt = "";
    // Set Processing to false to indicate
    // that the method is done processing
    Processing = false;
    // Call StateHasChanged to refresh the UI
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Execute a function

```
private List<ChatMessage> ExecuteFunction(
    ChatCompletions ChatCompletionResult, List<ChatMessage> ParamChatPrompts)
    {
        // Get the arguments
        var functionArgs =
        ChatCompletionResult.Choices.FirstOrDefault()
        .Message.FunctionCall.Arguments.ToString();
        // Get the function name
        var functionName =
        ChatCompletionResult.Choices.FirstOrDefault()
        .Message.FunctionCall.Name;
        // Variable to hold the function result
        string functionResult = "";
        // Use select case to call the function
        switch (functionName)
        {
            case "Todos_POST":
                var NewTODO =
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ToDoAddRequest>(functionArgs);
                if (NewTODO != null)
                {
                    functionResult = AddTodo(NewTODO.TodoRequest.todo);
                }
                break;
            case "Todos_GET":
                functionResult = GetTodos();
                break;
            case "Todos_DELETE":
                var DeleteTODO =
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ToDoRemoveRequest>(functionArgs);
                if (DeleteTODO != null)
                {
                    functionResult =
                    DeleteTodo(DeleteTODO.TodoIndexRequest.todoIdx);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // Return with the results of the function
        var ChatFunctionMessage = new ChatMessage();
        ChatFunctionMessage.Role = ChatRole.Function;
        ChatFunctionMessage.Content = functionResult;
        ChatFunctionMessage.Name = functionName;
        ParamChatPrompts.Add(ChatFunctionMessage);
        return ParamChatPrompts;
    }
```